# How can I convert MKV files and burn them to DVD?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, audio, dvd, file-conversion

I have a 5+1 theater system(can use USB or DVD) which doesn't support MKV play.

How can I use my Mac to burn the .mkv files into high quality dvds ?

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the mkv file first with something like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) or [iSkysoft's iMedia Converter](http://www.iskysoft.com/imedia-converter-mac.html), then burn it to DVD. Handbrake and iMedia Converter will give you more options for converting than Toast.

Comment: Convert to what though? Is it enough to convert the video to MPEG-2 and the audio to AC3 and the subtitles to text, or does the .mkv file need to be converted to an entirely different format? [I have a `.mkv` and `Handbrake` only offers to convert it to `.mkv` and `.mp4`.]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html). Toast will take individual video files and put them into a DVD player compatible format. It doesn't have many options for the DVD's menus, but it's a quick and easy way to burn video files to DVD. It also has many supported formats.

Comment: Toast will not burn mkv for me (Toast Titanium 11).