# Burn Movie to DVD on a Mac

Tags: macos, video, dvd-burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert MKV files and burn them to DVD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/how-can-i-convert-mkv-files-and-burn-them-to-dvd)

Does anybody know a good program for Mac that can burn a .avi or .mkv movie file to a DVD to play on any regular DVD player? I am looking for something like ConvertXtoDVD for Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html). Toast will take individual video files and put them into a DVD player compatible format. It doesn't have many options for the DVD's menus, but it's a quick and easy way to burn video files to DVD. It supports both AVIs and MKVs.

Comment: @Jaspack No problem!