# Whats a good software title to take video (mp4, avi, other..) and burn it to DVD

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, dvd, dvd-burning

I got some home brew videos from my webcam, and I got a couple movies on the drive I'd like to burn to DVD. The thing is, I don't know what's a good product for that, being a recent Mac convert and formally a heavy Windows user.

I keep finding things about iDVD when I search but from further reading iDVD is no longer available. So doing a quick search on google you get your standard "This app will do it all" type sites, usually really crappy software so I don't want to waste 20, 50, 100+ dollars on an app that I'll use once in a blue moon or on an app that's actually worthless.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/

Comment: Please stick to one topic for one questions, additional questions may easily be missed and will definitively making answering more difficult.

Comment: Most people will answer this question as if you were triying to burn data files ( that happen to be video files ) to a DVD-ROM. I'm sure you want to make a DVD-player-playable-movie DVD, in which case some convertion has to be done and even adding a menu. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to burn to DVD, you need a replacement for iDVD, and you don't want to spend beau coup cash, use [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html). Burn is free, and works swimmingly.

Comment: Great tool - just found it via this answer.  It won't recode to fit a target size if your films are larger than the disc size, but other than that it does everything that you need for making simple DVD from MP4 videos.

Comment: I see a "64-bit" and a generic for Burn (and a G3).  And both are more six years old and reference 10.3.9.  Will it still work on 10.13.2?  Will 64-bit be faster?

Answer (score 0):

- To burn DVDs: [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html)
- To rip DVDs: [RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) or [Mac The Ripper](http://www.macdvdripperpro.com/)
- To convert between video formats: [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), ideally together with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)