# How can I burn my iPhoto slideshow to DVD (to play in DVD player)?

Tags: macos, photos.app, dvd, slideshow

I can't figure out the way to burn my iPhoto slideshow to a DVD so I can play in a DVD player.

I am pretty sure this works out of the box but after googling, I only find paid software.  I am happy to pay but just want to make sure that I am not missing some out of the box solution.

Comment: did you try the Share > Burn

Comment: @Buscar - yes, i did and that doesn't create video DVDs so it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: As you found, "out of the box" is no longer true (unless you are still keeping an old copy of iDVD).  See some other questions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/   http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53931/